# Problem with proving continuity of this function

Tags: analysis, continuity

As the title says I came across a problem with this function:
$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous

$ f(x)=0 $, for  $ x\in\mathbb{Q}$

So i want to prove that this works for every real number:

$f(x)=0, x\in\mathbb{R}$

So my first idea was that i should somehow show that if that would'nt be true, that $f$ would not be continuous int he first place,but so far i am stuck at this.

Amy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \notin Q$, there is a sequence of rationale $a_n$ , $ n \in N$ converging to $x$ (the set of rational numbers is dense in the real numbers).

Because $f$ continuous, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Because $f(a_n)=0$ $\forall n$, we must have $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Would it work like this too?

Comment: @user246608 Sorry, I don't get what your are saying.

Comment: If i asume that for a non-rational real number x is not 0, then f  is not continious for rational x,but because f is continous it would cotradict.

Comment: Sorry i pressed post by accident before.